# Как сделать подгон изображения под размер слайдера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать подгон изображения под размер слайдера?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slider').rhinoslider({
    autoPlay: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/rhinoslider-1.02.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/easing.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="slide-box">
      <ul id="slider">
        <li><img src="/images/s1.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="/images/s2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="/images/s3.jpg"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: **[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: Имеется слайдер rhinoslider, когда я вставляю в него свою картинку слайдер его обрезает, мне нужно чтоб слайдер подгонял изображение под свой размер. http://www.rhinoslider.com/ сайт слайдера

Comment: вопрос на столько непонятный... ну вот сам со стороны прочитай свой вопрос и попытайся на него ответить? не зная какие картинки (в смысле размер), какова область под которую надо подогнать, ну вот я тебя спрошу...  ты мне ответишь?

Comment: max-width:100%  в любой непонятной ситуации

Comment: #slider {
 width:990px;
 height:300px;
размер картинки 1280 x 720

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае должно помочь, если просто прописать картинкам слайдера высоту и ширину в 100%.

```
#slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Ещё можете поиграться со свойством **object-fit**.

Пример кода на [**CODEPEN.IO**](https://codepen.io/apavlovs/pen/KyzxaE)